# Firebase basics - JavaScript and forms validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, validation, firebase

I want to use Firebase to create coupon codes database. My data structure is following:

```
[
    { 
        "couponCode": "string",
        "isAvailable": true
    },
    {
        "couponCode": "string",
        "isAvailable": true
    },
    ...
]
```

I wont to get `couponCode` key value and next check value for `isAvailable` key. If  `couponCode` is valid I want to change value for `isAvailable` key to **false**. How to create this validation using Firebase API?

Comment: Answer below. But please read the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/) before continuing on your path. A few hours spent in the quickstart and guide will prevent many future questions and problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If couponCodes are unique, you're probably better off storing the data like this:

```
"couponCodes": {
  "couponCode1": {
    "available": true
  },
  "couponCode2": {
    "available": true
  }
}
```

Now if a user is trying to claim a coupon, you run a [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) on that code:

```
ref.child('couponCodes').child('couponCode1').transaction(function(current) {
  if (current && current.available) {
    current.available = false;
    // TODO: this is the moment that you'll also want to give the user the discount for the coupon
  }
  return current;
});
```